# PHP PDO Postgres database start/stop issue

Tags: php, postgresql, yii, pdo

I'm using Yii with postgres database in support library of PDPPDO.

I am facing issue in PDO library to conenct Postgres Database.

I'm using some background process to work so ultimately it will be 24X7 continues task. Now, As per use case it's possible that my Postgres will go OFF/Crash somehow. That time, pg_prepare() function returning me FALSE.. That's tottaly Corrent !!!

Now, after few minutes, if Postgres get start. So ultimately pg_prepare() should give me resource Id. But it's still giving me FALSE !!

I believe that due to restarting postgres server it's not allowing me to use same resource again. In that case I need infinite loop that willy continuously ping over Postgres for new connection.

If need to open connection again then I think following like would help,

```
    // THOUGH IT'S CHECKING FOR $this->_pdo 
    // I need to make it NULL before process...
    Yii:app()->db->open();
```

Now, Is that right flow? or do you guys have any other idea for this?

Thanks ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing plenty of research, found that there isn't any solution for automatically inform Yii that connection is started again. So to maintain this, I am keeping one flag internally to check connection.

In Yii, to reconnect any database you need to delete previous connection using,

```
    Yii::app()->db->setActive(false);
```

It will remove all your previous connection and sources and allow you to make connection again using,

```
    Yii::app()->db->setActive(true);
```

If still not able to find connection then we can delay our background job for few minutes. Benefit, you don't need to restart your background workers.

Regards